# QGIS 2.14.9 refuses to open GeoPackage file

Tags: qgis, sqlite, geopackage

I tried to open in QGIS 2.14.9 a .gpkg file but this action resulted in an error message stating that the file is not a valid or recognised data source. However, QGIS includes support for the GeoPackage format, it can see the file listed in its directory when I choose this type of file in the "Open" window (for vector layer) and lets me select it to perform the "Open" action.

Any ideas about what may be wrong? The file in question has been downloaded from this service:

https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc2018?tab=download

(SQLite Database option)

Comment: I'm not sure how much support there was for GeoPackages that long ago - try using version 3.14

Comment: People are not so eager to download 3.5 GB files from a site that requires registration. I suggest you to download first the newest QGIS and GDAL and check with them if they can open the data.

Comment: I understand that no one wants to download 3.5 GB files to check; I just wanted to show what kind of data I tried, in the case someone has already experience with that.

Comment: I believe I will download the data it there is a failure with QGIS 3.12/3.14. QGIS 2.14 was released in March 2016 but you are right, someone else may still be using it.

Comment: does it open and write other gpkg files?

Comment: you say you are downloading the "SQLite Database option" that is no the same as a GeoPackage.

Comment: In the file listing they say "SQLite Database" but the file I receive has the .gpkg extension. The command "file" informs me that it is a SQLite 3.x database, user version 10200.

Comment: I tried to open another .gpkg file which is SQLite 3.x database (without user version like previously). That one worked. So, there are some compatibility issues between versions of the GeoPackage file format and QGIS. I guess QGIS version 3.14 will do the trick but I cannot test it (I am not the administrator of the workstation).